# Python: Get single words from a string

Tags: python, string, parsing, char

i'm trying to make a string analyzer in python. I'm starting with this input as example:

`toAnalyze= "Hello!!gyus-- lol\n"`
and as output i want something like that:

`>Output: ['Hello', '!!', 'guys', '--', ' ', 'lol']`
I want every gropus sorted in the original order

I have thought to scan all chars in the original string until the "\n" character and i came up whith this solution:

```
toAnalyze= "Hello!!gyus-- lol\n"
final = ""
for char in toAnalyze:
    if char != " \n\t" and char != " " and char != "\n" and char != "\n\t":
            final += char
    elif char == " " or char == "\n" or char == "\n\t" or char == " \n\t":
        if not final.isalnum():
            word= ""
            thing = ""
            for l in final:
                if l.isalnum():
                    word += l
                 else:
                    thing += l
            print("word: " + word)
            print("thing: " + thing )
```

And my current output is:

`>Output: thing: !!-- word: Hellogyus lol`

Do you have and idea?
The output wanted :

`>Output: ['Hello', '!!', 'guys', '--', ' ', 'lol']`

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: first of all `char` is a single character here like `"a"` or `" "` or `"\n"`, not `" a"` or `"\n\t"`

Comment: That's true, indeed

Comment: next, you want the output to be an array of words and separators, but your `word` and `thing` are strings

Comment: what do you want to use as the separators ?

Comment: I know that word and thing are string, i can always save them in the list. As separator i would use all the non alphanumeric character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a python guy, but want to help you to get started. This is the working solution which you can try to improve so that it becomes more pythonist:

```
toAnalyze= 'Hello!!gyus-- lol\n'

word = ''
separator = ''
tokens = []

for ch in toAnalyze:
    if ch.isalnum():
        word += ch
    
    # we met the first character of a separator, so save a word
    if not ch.isalnum() and word:
        tokens.append(word)
        word = ''
        
    # 1. we met the first alphanumeric after a separator, so save the separator or
    # 2. we met a new separator right after another one, also save the old separator
    if ch.isalnum() and separator or separator and separator[-1] != ch:
        tokens.append(separator)
        separator = ''
       
    if not ch.isalnum():
        separator += ch
```

The output for your example is:

```
['Hello', '!!', 'gyus', '--', ' ', 'lol']
```